# How do I integrate Stockfish into html and php project

Tags: php, laravel-5, chess

I want to simulate a chess game where the moves are taken from the database. I would like to have a stockfish engine check to see if the moves are being played correctly, while taking the moves from the database. How can I control this with stockfish?

Answer (score 0):

Stockfish provides an executable, written in C++

You'll need to integrate that bin with your PHP backend (I'm not sure, but maybe `proc_open` will do it?)

Stockfish uses the UCI Protocol as described here: http://support.stockfishchess.org/kb/advanced-topics/uci-protocol

Comment: Can I use only the initial functions of stockfish? For example making moves.

Comment: It looks like you can use any stockfish function from `Setting the position` to `Analyzing the move`, according to that link. So you can feed it a position, and then check what the score for a position. I'm not sure what the analysis returns, but I figure it's got what you are looking for